# High speed counter for digital oscilloscope

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, oscillator, oscilloscope

I'm designing a simple digital oscilloscope, as a learning exercise. It will do the trivial: to sample the analog signal and store it in high speed SRAM and them plot the data to an LCD.

The part that I need help with, is the block that will trigger the ADC and control the SRAM to grab each sample and store it in a given address. I'm still choosing parts and sketching the design, and I would like to hear about the possible approaches.

I have been looking at various open source and commercial projects, and all of them use an FPGA to do this task.

Wouldn't be possible to use some high speed 74XX devices to do that? Are there any reasons to avoid this approach? The oscillator that will trigger the ADC (and also increment de SRAM address) will be about 40MHz. In addition to that, there will be some control signals to start / stop the oscillator, reset the counter and to command the SRAM to read / write data.

Is there any complication I didn't foresee, that will make an FPGA the only practical option?

I would like to hear from more experienced engineers before choosing an approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's doable without an FPGA - ask yourself how you'd implement a design that has only a 40 kHz clock then look at data sheets to see what problems may arise due to rise/fall times and propagation delays at 40 MHz clocking. Maybe use a sim. Don't know if LTSpice can run logic sims but, if it can it's well worth looking at before implementing hardware. Unfortunately your question isn't a good fit for this site (IMHO) so I'm voting to close it.

Comment: @Andyaka, thanks for the comment, and sorry if the question doesn't fit here.

Comment: using an FPGA has following advantages: (1) faster (2) smaller (3) maybe cheaper (4) the test-debug-fix cycle during development is much faster

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use a FIFO chip, which has the write and read address counters built-in. Also, remember that you don't need to start/stop the oscillator, ADC, etc. You can let them run continuously, and simply choose which of the samples actually get written to memory by gating the write enable signal.

Comment: @DaveTweed, thanks for your tips, regarding FIFO chips and continuous ADC sampling! That will make design way simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is possible (just barely) with 74xx ICs, as long as you don't need excessive trigger logic complexity, and as long as "xx" means something other than 7400 series.

The 74FCT family will give you counters and registers up to about 100 MHz, so that's no problem. The hard part will be digital triggering. By this, I mean that you continually run the ADC, and examine the digital output to determine trigger status. Your best bet would be to use 74F85s in a pipeline configuration, and theoretically you can get about 40 MHz for 8 bits. 12 bits would be harder, but I suspect you could get tricky and get it to work.

Using a RAM, you need to produce a 40 MHz counter to determine acquisition window, so using a FIFO will be a big win in complexity as long as you want a data window which is the same size as the FIFO, since you can play with the FIFO full/FIFO empty flags to control your read and write functions rather than using an external counter to control your read and write bursts. It would have the advantage of decoupling the read and write functions to the RAM/FIFO (no need for address and data multiplexers).